# add header for every request of retrofit2

Tags: java

I am add a interpreter in retrofit like this:

```
 public static Retrofit InitRetrofitOkhttp(String configKey) {
        String tenantId = MyContext.getCurrentTenantId() == null ? "" : MyContext.getCurrentTenantId().toString();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header(MyContext.VERIFY_TENANT_ID, tenantId);
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        Config config = ConfigService.getAppConfig();
        String baseUrl = config.getProperty(configKey, "127.0.0.1");
        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
        Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
        retrofitBuilder.client(client);
        retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(baseUrl);
        retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit sRetrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();
        return sRetrofit;
    }
```

what I want to do is add different tenant_id in every http request, but it seems only the first time initial retrofit add interpreter(I could not debbugging in interpreter), what should  I do to make it work? I did not know I do like this works.

Answer (score 1):

Move

`String tenantId = MyContext.getCurrentTenantId() == null ? "" : MyContext.getCurrentTenantId().toString();`

into `intercept` method